# How to restrict PanGesture on subivews in ios

Tags: ios, gestures

I have a view which is having pan gesture. i am adding date picker as subview to that view. when i pan on date picker that pan gesture is getting fired. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fastest way would be to set the `userInteractionEnabled` of the view to `YES/NO` when you remove/add the picker. This is useful only if you don't want  any gesture when the picker is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 6 introduces a great new feature that solves this exact problem - a UIView (subview) can return NO from gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: (gesture recognizer attached to a superview). Indeed, that is the default for some UIView subclasses with regard to some gesture recognizers already (e.g. a UIButton with regard to a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to a superview).

See matt's book on this topic: [matt's book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizers)

Comment: Thanks syed. it helps me a lot.